# How to properly handle switching view controllers/scenes?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I'm having an issue with scene/view controller management in my Swift 2 app. From my main menu, the user can tap to start playing the game, which works great. While playing the user has the choice to leave prematurely via a UIButton, or the app will automatically move them back to the main menu when they lose.

The issue arises after a couple cycles of playing, redirecting to the main menu, and so on. The FPS while playing drops significantly, which indicates to me some sort of scene management inefficiency that I'm overlooking.

The main menu is a storyboard with a segue to the playing state, which is consisted of 2 parts. The storyboard containing the basic UI elements, and an SKScene that renders SpriteKit elements on top of the storyboard. To go back, I have a rewind segue for whenever the user touches the back to main menu button, and some different code for automatically moving them back, as so (contained within the SKScene):

```
func goHome()
{            
    self.viewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    self.removeAllChildren()
    self.removeFromParent()
}
```

When the play button in the main menu is tapped, I have a segue that leads to the PlayViewController, and I have the following in the PlayViewController's viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size, controller: self)
    skView = view as! SKView
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

This is a bit of a complicated issue, so I apologize in advance if my explanation was a bit confusing. But if anybody could shed some light on what's causing the performance problems, that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: "The issue arises after a couple cycles of playing, redirecting to the main menu, and so on" - sounds more like a memory leak to me. Swift does a lot automatically, but maybe there's something in your drawing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may not lie in your scene management but instead with sprites or the scene not being properly deallocated. None of your code here gives me enough information to tell you what is exactly causing the problem though.

Comment: You were right, I was looking at completely the wrong thing. It turns out, a wrapper I made for some SKSprites were causing the performance issues, so now I know what I need to fix. Thanks for opening my eyes!